# How can I add a git submodule with the same name as an old, deleted git directory?

Tags: git, local, directory, git-submodules

I'm trying to turn a directory into a submodule and effectively turn the thing into a git superproject/project with specialized submodules inside.  I have a "built" directory (necessary for what I'm making, as some of the dependencies are closed-source and therefore not in the git repo, meaning that some people can't build their own version), but I want to turn it into a separate repo placed in the same location as before.  That is, instead of being `/built` as a directory tracked by the repo, I want it to be `/built` as a submodule tracked by a different repo.

However, when I try deleting `/built`, committing that, and executing `git submodule add BUILT_REPO_URL built`, I get:

```
A git directory for 'built' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin        BUILT_REPO_URL
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  BUILT_REPO_URL
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

(I have substituted BUILT_REPO_URL for the appropriate git repository hosting URL.)

I don't want to rename the directory because that seems odd and I have build scripts and whatnot that I'd have to change.  Besides, there are other directories I want to do this to as well, and they have a fairly set directory structure based on the framework I'm using.  I've tried removing files from the cache (didn't have them there) and other similar steps.  The problem is also un-Googleable, since all the results I've found have been for changing a submodule to a different submodule with the same directory name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have first remove and committed the '`built`' folder.

```
git rm -rf built
# or, if built isn't in the working tree
git rm --cached -rf built
git add -A
git commit -m "remove built"
```

Then you can try your `git submodule add`.

Comment: Turns out I went full space cadet and forgot that I'd already tried adding built as a subdirectory months ago, meaning it was still lurking in `.git/modules/`.